# CX_SY_CONVERSION_NO_NUMBER when divide on i type?

Tags: abap, division

I am trying to divide my 2 number. And I determine them with different type. I am getting error when I try to divide them.

But my point is, when I am in debug, why does the first number show '*'? The problem is happening because of this.

```
EXCEPTION :  CX_SY_CONVERSION_NO_NUMBER


DATA : sayi1, sayi2 TYPE i.
DATA : sonuc TYPE p LENGTH 3.

BREAK-POINT.
sayi1 = 16.
sayi2 = 19.

sonuc  = sayi1 / sayi2.

WRITE : / sonuc.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should define every parameter differently in ABAP, you cant do it with like one "type i" :) its not like other languages such as C, C++, Java :)

So it should be like this:

```
DATA : sayi1 type i,
       sayi2 TYPE i.
DATA : sonuc TYPE p LENGTH 3.
```

Hope it was helpful

Talha

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that the determination rules in ABAP, what I dont understand is when I define the variables like in my example, first variable return '*' in debug mode. Why is this happen?

Comment: When you define your parameter without a type, it will be defined as char1, 1 character char. I personally use that when I need to use a flag. Like, data: lv_flag.